# Как отключить кнопку "оплатить" в заказах со статусом Обработка

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как отключить кнопку "оплатить" напротив заказов со статусом "Обработка"?

После оплаты заказ изменяет статус на "обработка"- это правильно.
В разделе "Заказы" пользователь видит этот же заказ с кнопкой "Оплатить", где может случайно оплатить его дважды и более раз. Это неправильно.

Например, в заказах со статусом "Отменен" и "Возращен" - этой кнопки нет.

Ссылка проблемы - https://yadi.sk/i/UkmOqhb2n9-nIQ

Comment: Картинки должны быть в теле вопроса

Comment: На вашей картинке какая-то нестандартных тема. Переключите на storefront, например, и проверьте

Comment: Решено. Конфликт с плагином https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/yandex-money-checkout/